# Why there is no static destructor?

Tags: .net, memory-management, static

I try to avoid using static classes in my production code as they cant be injected, there is no control over default initialization and lastly you can't really clean up your resources implicitly as there is no destructor for static objects. Additionaly, you cannot implement the IDisposable for a static class as well, so sounds like static classes are never good for being a wrapper around unmanaged resources...
It totally seems like singletons are a better solution to replace the use of static classes directly in that case. But my question is - why doesn't the compiler support static destruction, after all what difference does it make for the GC to keep track of references to a static object vs an instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "static object". But all static variables in all types loaded in any app domain are treated as GC roots until the app domain is unloaded.

If you want to do things when the app domain is unloaded, you could subscribe to [AppDomain.DomainUnload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainunload.aspx) and [AppDomain.ProcessExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, so I guess my question is, since static classes are convinient avenue to use for wrapping some resources (File handlers, pInvoke, whatever), what would be the best approach to clean those up?

Comment: @Max: I typically wouldn't wrap resources in that way anyway, to be honest. File handles in particular are almost always best disposed of as soon as you can.

Comment: OK, I think I have my opinion validated against the pros as far as static vs singletons.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Aren't singleton a static objects ?

Comment: @dnkulkarni: There's no such term, so how could a singleton be one? You can describe what *you* may mean when you use the term "static object" but it's not official terminology.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : ok well. I am been caught in the words but then what would you call this field in a class :  public static myclass mcl =  new myclass();     Isn't mcl is static object ?  is there different name to this  ?

Comment: @dnkulkarni: No, `mcl` is a static *field*. It's not an *object*. It's very important to distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a static destructor, won't an `AppDomain.DomainUnload` event work?